# Associate incrementally items between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables.
First contains some activations, second contains some deactivations.

I have to associate one deactivation with only one activation using the folowing rules:

- The activation must precede the deactivation but not be older than
  92 days.
- An activation already associated with a deact cannot be associated
  again.

So, using some data:

```
--a activations, b - deactivations
create table a (id1 integer, date1 date);
create table b (id2 integer, date2 date);

insert into a values (1, '1-Feb-2013');
insert into a values (2, '2-Feb-2013');
insert into a values (3, '3-Feb-2013');
insert into a values (4, '1-Mar-2013');
insert into a values (5, '2-Mar-2013');
insert into a values (6, '1-May-2013');
insert into a values (7, '19-May-2013');

insert into b values (1, '1-May-2013');
insert into b values (2, '1-May-2013');
insert into b values (3, '15-May-2013');
insert into b values (4, '16-May-2013');
insert into b values (5, '17-May-2013');
insert into b values (6, '18-May-2013');
```

Desired output:

```
id1 date1                           id2     date2                           
1   February, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 1   May, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000  1   1   
2   February, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 2   May, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000  2   2   
4   March, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000    3   May, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000  4   3   
5   March, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000    4   May, 16 2013 00:00:00+0000  5   4   
6   May, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000      5   May, 17 2013 00:00:00+0000  6   5
```

A query to generate the candidates would be:

```
select id1, date1, id2, date2
from a
join b 
on a.date1 >= b.date2 - 91 
and b.date2 >= a.date1;
```

I succeed to create a correct query using connect by but is too slow (I have milions of clients with thousands of activations and deactivations of devices per client. The example is for one client.)

```
with  chrn as
(
select id1, date1, id2, date2,
      dense_rank() over (  order by date1, id1) as act_ord, 
      dense_rank() over ( order by date2, id2) as deact_ord 
from a
join b 
on a.date1 >= b.date2 - 91 
and b.date2 >= a.date1
)
select * 
from (
  select s.*, row_number() over (partition by lvl order by act_ord+deact_ord) as rnk
  from (
      select a1.*, level lvl 
      from chrn a1
       connect by 
       prior deact_ord < deact_ord and 
       prior act_ord < act_ord and 
      (prior deact_ord = deact_ord - 1 or prior act_ord = act_ord - 1) 

      start with deact_ord = 1 and act_ord = 1
  )s
)where rnk =1
;
```

[see sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/816d8/18)

I want to find a faster solution for this, maybe using only analytic functions. The recursive query is too slow caused by the high number of candidates and paths. Or I didn't succeed to reduce the number of candidates and paths.

Comment: does id have to anything with the relations ship between activation and deactivation ???

Comment: No, it's just an identifier of a row in my example. I have another key.

Comment: First thing you are not using partition by here, please use Rank rather then dense rank, both will give same result but rank will perform 25% better give or take. looking in the query for further changes , you plz try altering this

Comment: Thanks, but I see the problem is at connect by(the number of row explodes) and maybe at row_number (the number of records resulting after connect by being huge).

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements cannot scale well with an increasing number of records because all preceding pairs have to be found in order to find the next pair.

Sure, as long as you have to do this only once there's no way around this. But if you have to find new pairs frequently, I'd strongly suggest to add a `deact_id` to `table1` and

```
create or replace trigger BI_B after insert on B for each row
begin
  for c in 
   (select rowid 
    from   A
    where  date1    >= :new.date2 - 91 
      and  date1     < :new.date2
      and  deact_id is null 
    order by date1
   )
  loop
    update A
    set    deact_id = :new.id2
    where  rowid    = c.rowid;

    exit;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: interesting ideea. Actualy, I cannot alter the facts tabels, but this is the ideea to do this programatically, without using pure sql. For every new disconnection I should find first activation not assigned yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE A ( ID1  INTEGER,
              DATE1 DATE );

CREATE TABLE B ( ID2  INTEGER,
              DATE2 DATE );

INSERT INTO
      A
VALUES
      ( 1,
        '1-Feb-2013' );

INSERT INTO
      A
VALUES
      ( 2,
        '2-Feb-2013' );

INSERT INTO
      A
VALUES
      ( 3,
        '3-Feb-2013' );

INSERT INTO
      A
VALUES
      ( 4,
        '1-Mar-2013' );

INSERT INTO
      A
VALUES
      ( 5,
        '2-Mar-2013' );

INSERT INTO
      A
VALUES
      ( 6,
        '1-May-2013' );

INSERT INTO
      A
VALUES
      ( 7,
        '19-May-2013' );

INSERT INTO
      B
VALUES
      ( 1,
        '1-May-2013' );

INSERT INTO
      B
VALUES
      ( 2,
        '1-May-2013' );

INSERT INTO
      B
VALUES
      ( 3,
        '15-May-2013' );

INSERT INTO
      B
VALUES
      ( 4,
        '16-May-2013' );

INSERT INTO
      B
VALUES
      ( 5,
        '17-May-2013' );

INSERT INTO
      B
VALUES
      ( 6,
        '18-May-2013' );

COMMIT;

BEGIN
    DBMS_STATS.SET_TABLE_STATS ( OWNNAME     => 'REALSPIRITUALS',
                            TABNAME  => 'A',
                            NUMROWS  => 100000000  );
END;
/

BEGIN
    DBMS_STATS.SET_TABLE_STATS ( OWNNAME     => 'REALSPIRITUALS',
                            TABNAME  => 'B',
                            NUMROWS  => 100000000  );
END;
/
```

**Your Query**

```
SET AUTOTRACE ON

WITH CHRN
    AS (SELECT
             ID1,
             DATE1,
             ID2,
             DATE2,
             DENSE_RANK ( )
                 OVER ( ORDER BY
                           DATE1,
                           ID1 )
                 AS ACT_ORD,
             DENSE_RANK ( )
                 OVER ( ORDER BY
                           DATE2,
                           ID2 )
                 AS DEACT_ORD
        FROM
                 A
             JOIN
                 B
             ON A.DATE1 >= B.DATE2
                        - 91
                AND B.DATE2 >= A.DATE1)
SELECT
      *
FROM
      (SELECT
            S.*,
            ROW_NUMBER ( )
                OVER ( PARTITION BY LVL
                      ORDER BY
                          ACT_ORD
                          + DEACT_ORD )
                AS RNK
       FROM
            (SELECT
                   A1.*,
                   LEVEL LVL
             FROM
                   CHRN A1
             CONNECT BY
                      PRIOR DEACT_ORD < DEACT_ORD
                   AND PRIOR ACT_ORD < ACT_ORD
                   AND ( PRIOR DEACT_ORD = DEACT_ORD
                                      - 1
                       OR PRIOR ACT_ORD = ACT_ORD
                                      - 1 )
             START WITH
                   DEACT_ORD = 1
                   AND ACT_ORD = 1) S)
WHERE
      RNK = 1;
```

**Going by CBO on your query:**

```
       ID1 DATE1            ID2 DATE2        ACT_ORD  DEACT_ORD        LVL      RNK
---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------      ----------
         1 01-FEB-13          1 01-MAY-13          1          1          1         1
         2 02-FEB-13          2 01-MAY-13          2          2          2         1
         4 01-MAR-13          3 15-MAY-13          4          3          3         1
         5 02-MAR-13          4 16-MAY-13          5          4          4         1
         6 01-MAY-13          5 17-MAY-13          6          5          5         1

5 rows selected.

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
   0       SELECT STATEMENT Optimizer Mode=ALL_ROWS (Cost=16 G Card=25000 G Bytes=2235174G)
   1    0    TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION
   2    1      LOAD AS SELECT
   3    2        WINDOW SORT (Cost=7 G Card=25000 G Bytes=1024454G)
   4    3          WINDOW SORT (Cost=7 G Card=25000 G Bytes=1024454G)
   5    4            MERGE JOIN (Cost=2 G Card=25000 G Bytes=1024454G)
   6    5              SORT JOIN (Cost=667123 Card=100 M Bytes=2G)
   7    6                TABLE ACCESS FULL SRINIV.A (Cost=770 Card=100 M Bytes=2G)
   8    5              FILTER
   9    8                SORT JOIN (Cost=667123 Card=100 M Bytes=2G)
  10    9                  TABLE ACCESS FULL SRINIV.B (Cost=770 Card=100 M Bytes=2G)
  11    1      VIEW (Cost=9 G Card=25000 G Bytes=2235174G)
  12   11        WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK (Cost=9 G Card=25000 G Bytes=1932494G)
  13   12          VIEW (Cost=887 M Card=25000 G Bytes=1932494G)
  14   13            CONNECT BY NO FILTERING WITH START-WITH
  15   14              COUNT
  16   15                VIEW (Cost=887 M Card=25000 G Bytes=1629814G)
  17   16                  TABLE ACCESS FULL SYS.SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6820_3AD00CE0 (Cost=887 M Card=25000 G Bytes=1024454G)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          2  recursive calls
          0  spare statistic 3
          0  gcs messages sent
          7  db block gets from cache
          0  physical reads direct (lob)
          0  queue position update
          0  queue single row
          0  queue ocp pages
          0  HSC OLTP Compressed Blocks
          0  HSC IDL Compressed Blocks
          5  rows processed
```

**New Query**

```
 SET AUTOTRACE ON


WITH CHRN
    AS (SELECT
             ID1,
             DATE1,
             ID2,
             DATE2,
             RANK ( )
                 OVER ( ORDER BY
                           DATE1,
                           ID1 )
                 AS ACT_ORD,
             RANK ( )
                 OVER ( ORDER BY
                           DATE2,
                           ID2 )
                 AS DEACT_ORD
        FROM
             A,
             B
        WHERE
             DATE2
             - DATE1 < 92
             AND ID1 = ID2)
SELECT
      *
FROM
      (SELECT
            S.*,
            ROW_NUMBER ( )
                OVER ( PARTITION BY LVL
                      ORDER BY
                          ACT_ORD
                          + DEACT_ORD )
                AS RNK
       FROM
            (SELECT
                   A1.*,
                   LEVEL LVL
             FROM
                   CHRN A1
             CONNECT BY
                      PRIOR DEACT_ORD < DEACT_ORD
                   AND PRIOR ACT_ORD < ACT_ORD
                   AND ( PRIOR DEACT_ORD = DEACT_ORD
                                      - 1
                       OR PRIOR ACT_ORD = ACT_ORD
                                      - 1 )
             START WITH
                   DEACT_ORD = 1
                   AND ACT_ORD = 1) S)
WHERE
      RNK = 1;
```

**Going by CBO on the new query:**

```
       ID1 DATE1            ID2 DATE2        ACT_ORD  DEACT_ORD        LVL      RNK
---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------      ----------
         1 01-FEB-13          1 01-MAY-13          1          1          1         1
         2 02-FEB-13          2 01-MAY-13          2          2          2         1
         4 01-MAR-13          3 15-MAY-13          4          3          3         1
         5 02-MAR-13          4 16-MAY-13          5          4          4         1
         6 01-MAY-13          5 17-MAY-13          6          5          5         1

5 rows selected.



Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
 0       SELECT STATEMENT Optimizer Mode=ALL_ROWS (Cost=538808 Card=5 M Bytes=457 M)
 1    0    TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION
 2    1      LOAD AS SELECT
 3    2        WINDOW SORT (Cost=436441 Card=5 M Bytes=209 M)
 4    3          WINDOW SORT (Cost=436441 Card=5 M Bytes=209 M)
 5    4            HASH JOIN (Cost=324556 Card=5 M Bytes=209 M)
 6    5              TABLE ACCESS FULL REALSPIRITUALS.A (Cost=770 Card=100 M Bytes=2G)
 7    5              TABLE ACCESS FULL REALSPIRITUALS.B (Cost=770 Card=100 M Bytes=2G)
 8    1      VIEW (Cost=102367 Card=5 M Bytes=457 M)
 9    8        WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK (Cost=102367 Card=5 M Bytes=395 M)
10    9          VIEW (Cost=5816 Card=5 M Bytes=395 M)
11   10            CONNECT BY NO FILTERING WITH START-WITH
12   11              COUNT
13   12                VIEW (Cost=5816 Card=5 M Bytes=333 M)
14   13                  TABLE ACCESS FULL SYS.SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6822_3AD00CE0 (Cost=5816 Card=5 M Bytes=209 M)

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
        2  recursive calls
        0  spare statistic 3
        0  gcs messages sent
        7  db block gets from cache
        0  physical reads direct (lob)
        0  queue position update
        0  queue single row
        0  queue ocp pages
        0  HSC OLTP Compressed Blocks
        0  HSC IDL Compressed Blocks
5  rows processed
```

Comment: Sorry, but this will not assign anything to deact no 3(because deact_ord = act_ord). The correct algoritm will match deact no 3 with act no 4. See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/816d8/21)